# What are XML Comments in C# Used For?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the virtues of using XML comments in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584901/what-are-the-virtues-of-using-xml-comments-in-net)

```
/// <summary>
///  Set error message for multilingual language.
/// </summary>
```

What is the use of XML Comments like the above in C# and when do i use them..
XML Comments come with 3 Quotes , Is there a block commenting process for XML Comments like /* ... */

Comment: MSDN tells you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx. They are for documentation purposes. They are also used by intellisense.

Comment: Real handy for generating help files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML comments are a structured way to document the types and members within your code.  If you use this, the compiler will generate XML documentation for your types and members, which can then be processed via a tool like [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) to build help automatically.  The information in the generated XML files is also used by Visual Studio (to provide intellisense).

You can use [multiline delimiters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fz4y783.aspx) via:

```
/** <summary>
Your info here
*/
```

Although the tooling doesn't generate it in this form.

For details, see [XML Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Its a way to document your code.  here is a reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx